# Is 30 minutes enough for a transit in Munich airport Terminal 2?

Tags: transit, airports, short-connections, muc

I have a flight from New York to Ankara via Munich. My flight to Ankara is just 30 minutes after the arrival of my first flight. Both flights are in Terminal 2. Is there a problem for such situations in Munich airport? I checked the map of the airport. There are 2 different Terminal 2 buildings. What's the difference?

Comment: A few years ago a satellite terminal building to terminal 2 opened at Munich to increase capacity. Unfortunately, I have not yet used that building so I can’t say how good or bad transfers are to and from it.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably only one airport in the world where you can do a 30 minute international -> international transfer - and that's Munich!  The airport has a "minimum connection time" (MCT) of 30 minutes for certain cases, and has a number of things in place to make such a connection possible.

However as is always the case with minimum connection times, that doesn't mean that you will make your flight, it just means that it's possible on a good day.  If your inbound flight is late, then your odds of making your connection very quickly go from good to zero.

In general, the best way to look at connections like this is to consider what happens if you do NOT make the connection.  Depending on the day, there appears to be one or at most two flights from Munich to Ankara per day - so if you do miss your connection, then you will have a delay of up to 24 hours.

Personally, given how few options there are to Ankara, I would never book such a connection unless you're willing to be delayed by up to a day.  The odds you'll make it are good, but the impact if you don't would rule it out for me.

Comment: Also remember that for short connections, even if you make it, your checked baggage may not, and may be placed on the next flight.

Comment: I consider Helsinki to be another one of those airports.

Comment: MCT at HEL is 40 minutes for D->I/I->D, and 35 for D->D, so a 30 minute connection would not be "legal" (not sure about I->I, but I doubt it's below 35)